# How do I build a house for my NPCs?

Tags: terraria

I read on the wiki that people will move in under the following conditions:

- You do something to please them
- An empty house is available with a light source, table, and chair (also with walls).

I have a house which is about 7x8, then a roof space above that; about half the area. I could put furniture up there too, but will anyone move in?

Comment: If you have built very small houses (6x6) and NPCs don't respawn, check my answer.

Comment: Making a change to the title; The title of "how do I build a house" + what is actually being asked for OP makes this a clear not duplicate for questions concerning how to specifically spawn an NPC, once the house is built. Questions about spawning the NPC that do not necessarily ask about building the house are being directed to this question, regardless

Comment: **There is still a valid answer to help users that have already provided valid housing, and are still having problems spawning NPCs**, but without that being reflected in the question, this is still not a valid "original" for any other question asking specifically about post-house NPC spawning (especially considering that current answers are not to be used in argument for a questions closure)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Houses need to fulfill a set
 of requirements to be considered a
 proper house. The step-by-step guide
 to making a house is as follows:

- The room must be at least [approximately 42 blocks away from any corruption](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Home#Corruption_Limit).
- Build the walls and roof. **The room must be five tiles tall at the least**,
  not counting the roof itself.
- The floor cannot be only wood platform, there must be a place for the NPC to stand without him standing on wood platforms.
  Make sure the room is big enough to be considered a proper house as well.
- **Fill in the house with background walls**. Any player-placed wall will work.
- **Place a light source inside the room**. A torch on the wall works fine, but
  you can also use candles and other
  such fancy items. You can make said
  fancy decorations with metals at an
  anvil.
- Place at least one "Comfort Item"(chair) and a "Flat Surface Item"(table) in the house.
- Place a Door in the house, in one of the walls.

Assuming you've done everything right,
 the game should treat your room as a
 house. **The first house you build will
 be taken by the Guide**, and any further
 houses by whichever NPCs appear.

There is also a size limit (60-750 tiles including walls, floor and ceiling), and **the first house you build will always go to the guide.**

Comment: Oddness on the height requirement.. I go 6 tall per room but that includes the Floor planks AND the ceiling planks so I only have 4 spaces of open air.. And yeah the Guide NPC is the first one to move in, but as I said I just do rooms, not houses :)

Comment: For me, a house is just a room with a sloped roof on top :)

Comment: You may want to update this answer as per 1.06 's new items

Comment: @Arperum Please don't edit quotes; they are supposed to actually be the words of the person who originally posted them.

Comment: @BillyMailman So an answer that contains blatantly wrong parts, where the poster is inactive for over a year and is accepted should just stay incorrect to confuse more people who search for it?

Comment: @Arperum Normally, no, but in this case, any edit to the quote is wrong, and edits that outright remove the quote are far too radical.  If you feel it's innacurate, that's what downvotes are for. Or just provide your own answer. Or use a bounty to ask for more quality answers and draw attention. Your call.

Comment: You can also check to see if your house is valid, rather than waiting in frustration to find out.  Open up your menu and there is a "social" option above your equipment.  With it open, you can change which NPCs live in which houses.  If you choose them, and try to choose the new house for them to live in, and it doesn't work, then it's not a valid house.

Comment: @BillyMailman No, those are quotes from the FAQ.  It's worse to keeping incorrect information.  Editing the accepted answer is the right thing to do here.  Now it's no longer quoting anything and people are free to edit in correct information.

Comment: To clarify the 2nd bullet point about the floor, you need at least 3 solid bricks next to the door for the NPC to stand on. The rest can be wood platforms.

Answer (score 17):

It has to to be 6 blocks tall and 7 blocks wide. It needs to be made from wood. It also needs to at least one chair, one table, a torch, and a wood floor.

NOW REMEMBER - You have to unlock all the NPC's. The Guide is the only one that's free. If he never moves in the house then just wait, it takes time. Leave the house for a while. Later, when you come back he will be in the house.

How to unlock NPC's

- Guns Dealer : Carry a gun in your inventory.
- Mechanic - You can find her in the Dungeon, just make sure to kill Skeletron before entering.
- Merchant - I think you need at least 50 silver coins.
- Demolitionist - You need at least one bomb in your inventory and the Merchant.
- Nurse - You need to have used at least one life crystal.
- Goblin Tinkerer - After you defeat the Goblin Army look on the map, then head to where he's at. When you first see him he will be called the Bound Goblin. Tap  (or click) on him and he will begin talking to you. Then make the house.
- Dryad - Defeat a boss, King Slime doesn't count.
- Santa Claus - It has to be somewhere around Christmas.
- Party Girl - Has a fairly rare chance to spawn after having eight NPC's. Also, make sure that the chat doesn't say (NPC's name) needs to settle down or she won't spawn.
- Truffle - Only spawns in Hardmode (activated after the defeating the Wall of Flash). Not only that, he can only spawn in player made surface glowing mushroom biome.
- Pirate - Only spawns in Hardmode. Is unlocked after defeating the Pirate Invasion.
- Wizard - Rare spawn underground after Hardmode is activated.
  There are some more but it will take lots of explaining.

REMEMBER - if you see a message like (NPC's name) needs to settle down, then build a house.

Comment: Just a short comment, I think the list of NPC's is now out of date. Could use a link to an external site. The steampunker for example is missing, as is the tiki dude.

Comment: Some missing NPCs:  Guide: No unlock required; shows up in new world, Painter: Aquire 7 other NPCs, Angler: find and speak to near ocean biome at either end of map, Witch doctor: defeat queen bee, Clothier: defeat Skeletron, Stylist: rescue from spider nest.

Comment: Only first paragraph is answering the question. The answer is wrong, there are many possible configurations (were they added later? I like 3x10 houses myself). And the rest is irrelevant (and also wrong.. kill Skeletron? Huh?). The upvoters never heard about [official wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com)? Note: this answer was given 3 years after question was asked.

Answer (score 14):

While it says empty 'house' it really means empty room. It needs to have a door as well as the light source, table chair and background walls (Also needs the walls that stop baddies from getting into it :))

There is a size requirement however, and I do not think the roof above a 7x8 house would be large enough to entice an NPC to stay there. (I usually build about 10x5 rooms or so and the NPCs never complain :))

Comment: Hm, ok. I don't want to start another question, but how much background wall is actually needed? i.e. behind the physical walls of the house? I can't get anyone to move in, and I have all of those.

Comment: You can have windows as wide as 2 x 2 blocks, and each window needs to be separated by at least one wall block in each direction. Technically, you can have as many windows as you can legally fix within those bounds, and they will move in. However, too many windows allows baddies to spawn in the room.

Answer (score 10):

NPC houses require all four sides to be covered (2 side walls, ceiling, and floor) and then have a background wall, a door, lighting, and furniture.  I usually make mine a little bigger than the space requirement, and I also put a door on BOTH walls just in case, have two torches in the ceiling corners and place a table and one chair on either side of it, all just to be safe.  The only other requirement that NPCs have is that the background wall is not a dirt wall, it's the only kind of wall they don't accept.  If that's what you were using then there's your problem. =)

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the other answers, it might be worth noting that your house can sometimes be too small even in its smallest allowed size.

This happened to me when I built 6 block by 6 block houses and the doors had been opened towards the interior of the house. This seemingly shrinks its size (I assume that's because an open door counts as wall).

I recommend building slightly bigger houses to compensate for this, or else NPCs won't respawn unless you close the doors.

Answer (score 9):

You need to have a building with a width of at least 10 and a height of at least 7, fully enclosed in walls. There must be background walls, a chair, a table, and torches.

Answer (score 8):

For the first house you build, and every other house, you have to have it be anywhere from 60-750 blocks for area (most people use 6x10 houses). There has to be a chair, and for the first house use a Workbench as the table. For the rest of the houses you should use a table because it will take up less wood. You also need full background (I recommend wood background since it will look nice and you can craft it easily) and a light source (1 torch will work). Finally, just place a door on either side.

That's all you need!

Answer (score 5):

Try building a 14 block wide house then cut it in half for a door to fit. Then put a crafting table and a chair in each part and select your npc. Click on the house and move so that you can't see the house and the npc should move in. Also you need to place a torch in the house for this to work. :)