# How do I find roommates?

Tags: terraria

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How large does a house need to be for residents to move in?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22408/how-large-does-a-house-need-to-be-for-residents-to-move-in)

I've created my first structure in Terraria and I've included all the important items that my guide told me to include so that someone moves in. This includes:

- walls
- a door
- a chair
- a table

When do NPCs move in? The guide also told me that there are certain extra requirements for special NPSs (he mentions a nurse and a merchant specifically) to move in, but are there "normal" NPCs that will move in with only the basic requirements met?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22408/how-large-does-a-house-need-to-be-for-residents-to-move-in

Comment: I didn't even see that. Since the answer there answers my question, I'm going to vote to close.

Comment: you might just flag it and ask the mods to close it as a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your guide has occupied that house. It isn't mentioned anywhere specifically in the game (which made it annoying for me to find), but the guide counts as an NPC in terms of occupancy.

The NPCs move in pretty much instantly if there is a house available for them (i.e. I finished my second house with plenty of silver, and it took 3 seconds for a merchant to appear).

There are no 'normal' NPCS as such - just the 'special' ones. You only need to build 6 or 7 houses to house everyone.