# How to make an NPC house

Tags: terraria

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How large does a house need to be for residents to move in?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22408/how-large-does-a-house-need-to-be-for-residents-to-move-in)

I seem to not have made my first house correctly; the Guide is not staying inside. How do you correctly construct a house for an NPC?

Comment: Hello itpres, and welcome to Gaming.Stackexchange! This question looks like it might be what you're looking for, and it already has some good answers. [Link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22408/how-large-does-a-house-need-to-be-for-residents-to-move-in)

Comment: The NPCs do walk in and out of their home.  Very annoying during a goblin invasion or blood moon.

Comment: A screencap of your house would help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good checklist:

- Have you got back wall that isn't dirt? Make sure to cover up holes.
- <s>Have you built it out of dirt blocks? If so, build it out of wood or stone.</s> lunboks has proven me wrong.
- Do you have a door?
- Do you have a chair and a table?
- (Not sure, but this coincidentally works for me) Have you got a worktable?
- Try building another house and waiting for another NPC. The Guide can be a little finicky - in mine he claimed his house, but stayed outside.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Dirt blocks work just fine, it's Dirt walls that don't. And a Work Bench definitely isn't needed.

Comment: @The Communist Duck

Comment: @The Communist Duck Yes, I have all that but he won't stay in... D:

Comment: Oh yeah, and while I'm at asking questions, how do you know if an NPC has moved in?

Comment: @itpres — You can tell an NPC has moved in because they will stand motionless in the room at night (assuming they have a way to get to it).  In addition to the items on TCD's list, you also need a light source (such as a torch) inside the house, and the house needs to be of a minimum size.  I've found that the ceiling needs to be at least five blocks high (two empty spaces above your head) and that the walls need to be a minimum of about 9 blocks apart.

Comment: And how do you set a bed as your spawn point?

Comment: @lunboks No, they don't.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck [Myth busted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/avMn4.jpg "Guide living in a Dirt house"), your turn.

Comment: @lunboks I take it back :)

Comment: @itpres - once you have built a proper house, you can place a bed inside. Right click the bed to set your spawn

Comment: @lunboks O RLY NAO?

Comment: And why is the merchant not coming? It's daytime and I have 52 silver coins.. isn't that more than enough?

Comment: Nevermind, he's here