# "Valid housing" - does this work?

Tags: terraria

OK just before I start, I **do** know what does and doesn't constitute [valid housing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22408/how-do-i-build-a-house-for-my-npcs) in Terraria. I'm also playing v1.2.4.1

What I'd like to know is does the "must have a door" requirement also mean "must be accessible", or can I create a walled-off cube with internal doors to satisfy the housing rules? i.e. are any of the houses A, B, C or D in the following diagram valid?

[image: House illustration]

If I can, then I'm going to be making pressure-plate/activator automatic doors that don't get torn down in a blood moon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that all of those have walls and a light source, those would count as valid housing. The requirement is that it has a door, not that the door go anywhere. Also notable is that [wooden platforms count as doors for the housing rule](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Base_defense_and_precautions#Reminder), so you can actually just have a wooden platform separate the rooms from each other as well.

Here is an example of housing with internal doors:

[image: Valid Housing with Internal Doors]

> If I can, then I'm going to be making pressure-plate/activator automatic doors that don't get torn down in a blood moon.

This is actually a very common strategy to defend from a blood moon. As noted in the [Base Defense Guide](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Base_defense_and_precautions) on the Wiki:

> By using actuators and Grey, Brown, Blue or Lihzahrd pressure plates, you can create a player only door that doesn't even require you to use your mouse. Setup the door as you would an active stone/actuator door and because Grey, Brown, Blue or Lihzahrd pressure plates can only be activated by the player no mobs are able to enter (nor escape).

You can also just place a torch or other item in front of the door so that it can only be opened when you are facing towards the outside. [From the wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Base_defense_and_precautions#Possible_Methods):

> Another way to prevent enemies breaking down your door is to place a non-solid object, such as a chest, wooden platform or other Furniture item, on the inside of the door. This will prevent enemies from opening it but will require the player to face away from the house to open the door.

Answer (score 2):

The structure does not have to be "accessible" with a door; as in you can create a switched active block entry way so that Blood Moon/Eclipse mobs can't get in.  You can also create a double door entry way, where the outer door is the switched active blocks.

Another way, would be to place a platform, container or decoration against the door.  This creates an "open from the inside only" door, that can't be opened inwards (the direction most mobs are headed to get inside your house).  The exception to this is goblin armies, as they break the door instead of opening it.  The "issue" is that YOU also can not open the door inwardly.  You would have to face out and click to open the door.

In your diagram, the C/D version where there is a switched "ceiling" between the doors is a good way to do it.

Comment: I currently use the double-door method so the outer door can only open outwards but I believe Goblin Armies and Blood Moon Zombies can still break the outer door and walk in. The main this is being able to up-scale the basic idea of a sealed box into a proper house, knowing that by the time I get round to building NPC houses at the top, it'll actually work :P Do you have any definitive source for it being valid housing?

Comment: I usually build an apartment complex that is above ground, and use a rope or hook system to get into it, then the event spawns mostly don't get in.  Goblin Sorcerers and Reapers being the notable (PITA) exceptions.  For the Goblins, I build a kill pit away from my houses, so that there are less unnecessary casualties.  :)

Comment: I'd rather not use rope, I'm taking a break from my normal MO and making a pretty house instead of a functional one :P

Answer (score 1):

I would say these are all valid if the requirements fit.

But you need to remember that the need to teleport into there houses wich means that you have to leave the place.

Second you need to think about monsters spawning in your house eg. Goblin Army.

third how will you talk with those npcs ?

Comment: Them teleporting in is fine. For monsters spawning inside, I'll be able to use the pressure plate/actuator door I mentioned (player-character only) and for talking to them, as before. The actual house will be much bigger than the illustration, but the plan is to completely seal it without traditional breakable doors Do you have any definitive source for it being valid housing?

Comment: @Joe than everything is ok!