# Who is Bradley (The Guide)?

Tags: terraria

I've been playing terarria for about 30 minutes and my guide died right at the beginning. Now it says "Bradley would like to settle down". How do I move him in?

Comment: Very much related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22408/how-do-i-build-a-house-for-my-npcs

Answer (score 3):

The guide is a character that is very important to the progression of terraria. If  you kill him (by any means), eventually, a new one will want to settle in. To do this, you must build a valid npc house, consisting of the following:

- Recommended 5x8 interior space
- One valid light source item (Torch, Tiki Torch, Candle, Skull Lantern, Candelabra, Lamp, Lantern, Chandelier, Chinese Lantern, Jack 'O Lantern, Christmas lights, Heart Lantern, Star in a Bottle)
- One flat surface item (Table, Dresser, Work Bench, Bathtub, Bookcase, Piano)
- One comfort item (Chair, Throne, Bench, Bed, Sofa)
- Background material

If your building reaches the requirements (you can check it using the '?' at the top of the inventory screen, then checking in your building), the NPC will eventually move into the building. This process is also what you need to do to attract other NPC's like the demolitionist, so it's a good idea to have this written down somewhere. However, full information on house requirements can be found [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/House), and a full list of NPC's [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC).

Comment: And don't forget to put the background walls inside the interior space. The already generated walls don't count.