# Why Isn't this Valid Housing? [Terraria PC]

Tags: pc, terraria

[image]

I was recently playing Terraria on my laptop when I saw that this was not valid housing. Why? I might be stupid and there could just be a simple answer but do any of you know?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This is a good question, but please try using the search function before asking a new question. Don't worry, this is a common mistake many people have made before :)

Comment: Houses can only be made of player-placed walls. You have to hammer all the dirt and snow walls, and then place some of your own

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the answer of the [How do I build a house for my NPCs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22408/how-do-i-build-a-house-for-my-npcs)

> - Fill in the house with background walls. Any player-placed wall will work.

The Snow background walls are not player placed, you need to replace them with something of your own.