# I built a NPC complex out of demonite ore!

Tags: terraria-mobile

None of the NPCs will move in, is it because of the ore? The building I have right next to it had a NPC in it already and now it is vacant. Is this also because of the ore?

Comment: That was no where near my question , nore do any of the answers for your unrelated Question remotely give me any information on my question . Put my Question back up please !!!

Comment: Voting to reopen. Given the specific nature of the question, the age of the "duplicate", and the fact that it is not at all covered by the answers, this question has merit. At the very least, let users actually have their say rather than abusing your diamond authority; we need 5 close votes for a reason. For shame.

Comment: Your question is in fact answered in the question I've linked. Arqade works a little differently than forums, as we like having all relevant information in one place instead of letting it scatter everywhere, making it harder to find. In essence, you're asking what makes a proper house, which was already asked and answered here before. If you look through the answers of the other question, you'll find the information you need. Having your question closed as duplicate is not a bad thing, it is how we help you find old information more quickly.

Comment: @Studoku Check out [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/22465/232393) on [one of the questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22408/how-do-i-build-a-house-for-my-npcs) that this has been closed as a duplicate of. It says that "The room must be at least approximately 42 blocks away from any corruption.", while providing a link that explains that demonite bricks are considered to be corruption. Please correct me if I got anything wrong, because I don't have the game myself. To me that sounds like it answers this question though.